# Creating dynamic table from db using php

Tags: php

I have tried but i could not just get where i am doing it wrong. The table only echo the first row continuously and did not echo the other rows. Kindly help please.

```
$run = "
                SELECT * FROM staff
                ";
        $runquery = mysqli_query($connection, $run);
        $runrow = mysqli_num_rows($runquery);
        if($runrow < 1){
            echo "<p class='errormsg'>You do not have any Staff</p>";
        }
        else{
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($runquery);
            if($row) {
                $surname = $row['surname'];
                $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                $phone = $row['phone'];
                $username = $row['username'];
                $role = $row['auth'];
            }
            foreach ($row as $staff) {
                $table .= "
                        <tr>
                            <td>$surname</td>
                            <td>$phone</td>
                            <td>$username</td>
                            <td>$role</td>
                        </tr>
            ";
            }

        }
```

Comment: because you are setting variables before loop.

Comment: Not working. I have tried that

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change loop like this. also the tabular view of your record require `<table>` body.

```
$run      = "SELECT * FROM staff";
$runquery = mysqli_query($connection, $run);
$runrow   = mysqli_num_rows($runquery);
if( $runrow < 1 ) {
    echo "<p class='errormsg'>You do not have any Staff</p>";
}
else {
    $table = ""; // create table here
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($runquery)) {
        $surname  = $row['surname'];
        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $phone    = $row['phone'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $role     = $row['auth'];
        $table .= "<tr>
                            <td>$surname</td>
                            <td>$phone</td>
                            <td>$username</td>
                            <td>$role</td>
                        </tr>";
    }
    echo $table;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Support Appreciated. But only the last row shows and nothing more. The code needs to be improved. I really appreciate your assistance. Kindly help

Comment: it is working fine as expected , try `print_r($row);` in loop

Answer (score 0):

did you try to move the following code part into the foreach-loop?

```
$run = "
        SELECT * FROM staff
        ";
$runquery = mysqli_query($connection, $run);
$runrow = mysqli_num_rows($runquery);
if($runrow < 1){
    echo "<p class='errormsg'>You do not have any Staff</p>";
}
else{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($runquery);
    foreach ($row as $staff) {
        $surname = $staff['surname'];
        $lastname = $staff['lastname'];
        $phone = $staff['phone'];
        $username = $staff['username'];
        $role = $staff['auth'];
        $table .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>$surname</td>
                    <td>$phone</td>
                    <td>$username</td>
                    <td>$role</td>
                </tr>
    ";
    }

}
```